# How can i switch my variable slideIndex declared to put it inside the object?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a slider, and this one works, but I need to put my slideIndex variable in the Slider object, to be accessible for my other prototypes but I do not find the way ..

It's for an html5 website, with basic css3 and Js. I exclude the other files you don't need.

```
'use strict';


var slideIndex = 0;

var Slider = function () {
    this.initSlider(slideIndex);
    this.moves = {
        number: moveInSlide(slideIndex)
    }
};


Slider.prototype.initSlider = function () {
    var i;
    var number;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("picture");

    if (number > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }

    if (number < 1) {
        slideIndex = x.length;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }


    x[slideIndex - length].style.display = "block";
};



function moveInSlide(number) {
    Slider.prototype.initSlider(slideIndex += number);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slideIndex` as a slider `property`:

```
var Slider = function () {
    this.initSlider(slideIndex);
    this.moves = {
        number: moveInSlide(slideIndex)
    }
    this.slideIndex = 0;
};
```